# How to use face values in obj files (opengl c++)

Tags: c++, opengl

```
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
v -1.0 -1.0 -1 0
v 1.0 -1.0 -1.0
v 0 -1.0 1.0
f 2 4 3
f 4 2 1
f 3 1 2
f 1 3 4
```

I have an obj file that describes a tetrahedron polygon.

I've finished coding to parse those data and save them into arrays.

To use the vertex values, I simply had to use glVertex3f(x, y, z)

But I don't know what I should do to use the face values.

I tried to follow some tutorials, but all of them seem very different from each other and it's really confusing.

Comment: The ones that use vertex buffer objects are the ones you should be paying attention to. The ones that use `glVertex3f` and similar functions are using old+deprecated OpenGL. In particular, it's easy to render this face format with indexed rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The face values tell you how use your vertices to create faces, for example, to create the first triangle (or face), from value f 2 4 3

```
 glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1 0f);    // vertex 2
  glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);    // vertex 4
  glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // vertex 3
glEnd();
```

You can find a complete example here, about create faces from vertices : http://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/c3/s1.html#gl1geom.1.1